# Pymongo: How to rewind a CommandCursor

Tags: cursor, pymongo

I have an aggreagte command `docs = self.collection.aggregate(query)`which returns a CommandCursor.

I would need to loop the CommandCursor twice, but unlike a usual cursor, the pymongo CommandCursor does not have a rewind or any similar method ([Docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html?highlight=commandcursor#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor)).

Do I have any chance to do that without converting the cursor to a dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rewind` option in `cursor` object calls the db again for the same query. So its also not a good option.

The best you can do is to convert the `commandCursor` object into list or tuple.

```
docs = list(self.collection.aggregate(query))
```

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did as a workaround. After the first loop I just call `docs = self.collection.aggregate(query)` again. But it shouldn't have too much performance issues since it is just a command cursor which is not executed yet. I prefer that right now over converting to list, cause the data load is quite large. Anyway, good to know what rewind does.

Comment: the major concern here is the number of db hits. We offen cross the db requests limits and that can crash our application at any time and also if you go to increase your db hit limit, it will cost you a lot of money. So We should try to reduce the number of db calls as much as we can and try to handle things in pythonic way which will cost us a bit more cpu but will be ok.